# Insert Array in Plugin Database

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

trying to create one plugin, getting some issue to submit the array data in wordpress database.

$formDATA gets the array value now issue is when

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `".$table_name ."` (`paid_arr`) VALUES '".$formDATA."'";

   $result  = $wpdb->insert($table_name,$formDATA);
```

getting strange warnings and errors not able to insert data in wp DB.

```
  Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /home3/mahesh/public_html/project/lal/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1316

 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home3/mahesh/public_html/project/lal/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1318

  Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home3/mahesh/public_html/project/lal/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1327
```

here is  php code;

```
$formDATA = array(
    'fname'     => $fname,
    'lname'     => $lname,
    'email'     => $paidemail,
    'Phone'     => $paidphone,
    'gender'    => $gender,
    'hobbies'   => $interest,
    'hear'      => $city,
    'message'   => $message_field,
    'time'      => $curtime
 );

formsubmitpaid($formDATA);       

function formsubmitpaid( $formDATA ) {

global $wpdb;
$formDATA = json_encode($formDATA);
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "padi_forms";
$sql = "INSERT INTO `".$table_name ."` (`paid_arr`) VALUES '".$formDATA."'";
$result  = $wpdb->insert($table_name,$formDATA);

if( !$result ){
    echo '<script>alert("dfdf")</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("No")</script>';
 }
print_r($sql);
print_r($result);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass data as an array, not a json encoded string. So changing these line would work. Just remove the following line -

```
$formDATA = json_encode($formDATA);
```

if you want to see the reference, prepare sql this way

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `".$table_name ."` (`paid_arr`) VALUES '".json_encode($formDATA)."'";
```

Comment: tried following code  not getting any error but not inserting data in my sql :  $sql = "INSERT INTO `".$table_name ."` (`paid_arr`) VALUES '".json_encode($formDATA)."'";
 $result  = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare($sql,$formDATA));
  $wpdb->show_errors();

Comment: No no no, not use the query. I mean, just delete the first line i mentioned, and leave everything as it is. Don't use the sql for inserting, i saw u used it for debugging, so i suggested you encode the data within the sql, not override the $formDATA variable

Comment: now getting following error: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Answer (score 1):

you can php [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) function to convert array to string before inserting to database. during retrieval, call [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to get the array back from string.

to insert:

```
$result  = $wpdb->insert($table_name,serialize($formDATA));
```

to retrieve:

```
   $result = unserialize($wpdb->get_col("SELECT paid_arr from $table_name"));
```

you can use json_encode and json_decode as well. but json_* functions are not available in older version of php.

Answer (score 1):

You need not have to `json_encode` the array as long as you have the table structure same as the form data key values. Reference: [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows)

```
$formDATA = array(
    'fname'     => $fname,
    'lname'     => $lname,
    'email'     => $paidemail,
    'Phone'     => $paidphone,
    'gender'    => $gender,
    'hobbies'   => $interest,
    'hear'      => $city,
    'message'   => $message_field,
    'time'      => $curtime
);

formsubmitpaid($formDATA);      

function formsubmitpaid($formDATA) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "padi_forms";    

    $result = $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        $formDATA, 
        array( 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s', 
            '%s' 
        ) 
    );  

    if( $result === false )
        echo 'Error';
    else 
        echo 'success';
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to write:  array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s', '%s','%s', '%s', '%s') ?

Comment: Yes, you should.. as that type of data you are inserting and the table's column data type should match. [Insert Rows](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows)

Comment: thanks, what other ways we  can insert the data in database? i check we can insert using prepare as well which is more easy because there will be large data later.

Comment: Read here regarding all the methods provided in $wpdb [Run any database query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database) --- & --- [Accept if it did solve.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/244824)

Comment: i am getting following error: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array

Comment: Can you please paste your whole code and the complete error string it is showing here ? Edit you question and add more info.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12046/discussion-between-subharanjan-and-jack-torris)